# Can i run an application(or stored procedure) and get result from trigger

Tags: c#, mysql, triggers

I want to create a trigger on table1 that inserts/updates table2.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_table1_update 
after UPDATE ON table1
BEGIN
FOR EACH ROW 
 Insert into table2
 SET password = OLD.password,
    name = OLD.name; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem here is that I want to first decrypt (old.password) and then hash it before inserting into the second table. I have a c# program that does it but how can i do it here?

Answer (score 1):

1. First you have to place your code between the 'BEGIN' and 'END$$'
   keywords.
2. Then you can declare a variable.
3. and search for the right function to decrypt the old password
4. store it in the variable
5. and insert it to the other table.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the BEGIN statement was a typo. can you please tell what you mean by "search for the right function to decrypt old password"? Is any function available or do i have to create it?

Comment: Which database server and encryption algorithm do you use?

Comment: Mysql database and encryption is Rijndael

Comment: So i think this is the right page for you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html